# finding noninterval sets that are either closed and unbounded or bounded and open

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I need to find an example of a closed set $E$ that is not an interval and not compact and a bounded set $F$ that is not an interval and not compact.

I'm really confused how to find this without using an interval

Answer (score 2):

Give $\mathbb{R}$ the discrete topology. Then $\mathbb{N}$ is closed (every set is closed in the discrete topology) in $\mathbb{R}$. But it is not compact nor is it an interval.

For the second part, give $\mathbb{R}$ its usual topology. Let $F = (0,1) \cup \{2\}$. It is not an interval, it is bounded, and it is not compact.

Comment: Your first example is true even with $\Bbb R$ having the usual topology: $\Bbb N$ is the complement of the open set $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,1)\cup (1,2)\cup \dotsc$, hence closed, and of course it's unbounded and not an interval. This is fortunate, because the way the problem is phrased tells me the examples are supposed to be in $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology: intervals have no special significance in the discrete topology.

Comment: You're right. Thanks, Brian.